# How to get all workday dates in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm trying to make a program in angular where employees can mark their work hours. But I can't figure out how to get all the workdates into an array. I tried this

```
getDaysInMonth(month, year) {
    this.date = new Date(Date.UTC(year, month,));
    this.days = [];
    while (this.date.getMonth() === month) {
      if(this.date.getDay() == 6 || this.date.getDay() == 0) {
        return "weekend";
      }
      this.days.push(new Date(this.date));
      this.date.setDate(this.date.getDate() + 1);
    }
    return this.days;
}
```

Comment: What are you getting with that code that's different from what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you return "weekend" from your if, which means that once you hit a weekend day, you will exit the function, return "weekend" and won't keep checking the other days.
here is a fixed snippet:

```
getDaysInMonth(month, year) {
  this.date = new Date(Date.UTC(year, month,));
  this.days = [];
  while (this.date.getMonth() === month) {
    this.date.setDate(this.date.getDate() + 1);
    if(this.date.getDay() == 6 || this.date.getDay() == 0) 
      continue;
     this.days.push(new Date(this.date));
  }
  return this.days;
}
```

Comment: But now every time when I try to generate the workdays my browser just crashes.

Comment: Can you debug this specific function and tell us what you see? that could be caused by something else.

Comment: Hi, you need to add `this.date.setDate(this.date.getDate()+1)` before the `continue`, otherwise it will be an infinite loop.

Comment: use a temporal variable for date (better let date=ne wDate(....) and date.setDate(date.getDate()+1) -or date=new Date(date.getTime()+24*60*60*1000))-

Answer (score 1):

The below code will give you dates of working days of a given month and year.

```js
function getWorkingDays(startDate, endDate){
     var workingDates = [];

    var currentDate = startDate;
    while (currentDate <= endDate)  {  
        var weekDay = currentDate.getDay();
        if(weekDay != 0 && weekDay != 6){
            workingDates.push(currentDate.getDate());
        }

         currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate()+1); 
    }

    return workingDates;
 }


function getDaysInMonth(month, year) {
     var begin = new Date(month + '/01/' + year);
     var end = new Date(begin.getFullYear(), begin.getMonth() + 1, 0);

     console.log(getWorkingDays(begin, end));
}

getDaysInMonth(11, 2019);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `return` stop the continuity of your `while` and your method, simply replace it by a `continue;` to stop the continuity of the current iteration of your while and to skip to the next one.

Answer (score 0):

This is a code I have developed in one of my projects, hope it solves your problem:

```
export function findWorkingDays(startDate: Date, endDate: Date): number {
    startDate = new Date(startDate.getFullYear(), startDate.getMonth(), startDate.getDate());
    endDate = new Date(endDate.getFullYear(), endDate.getMonth(), endDate.getDate());
    let days = 0;
    const curDate = startDate;
    while (curDate <= endDate) {
        const dayOfWeek = curDate.getDay();
        if (!((dayOfWeek === 6) || (dayOfWeek === 0))) {
          days++;
        }
        curDate.setDate(curDate.getDate() + 1);
    }

    return days;
}



findWorkingDays(new Date("01.10.2019"), new Date("31.10.2019"));
```